# x and y coordinates of a pinch-zoomed section of a page

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say we have a page with a `div` at the center which can be dragged and moved anywhere by the user. I can get the position of this rectangle using `getBoundingClientRect`. Everything is fine.

[image]

But now when I pinch-zoom (**not** `ctrl` + `+`) into the page and scroll to a section, I was expecting the `getBoundingClientRect` values to change but they don't, and that is understandable, as the values of `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY` also remain the same, which is `0` in this case.

But the thing is, how can I calculate the x and y coordinates of the pinch-zoomed section of the page which is currently visible with respect to the origin of the page.

[image]

Comment: You're right, I didn't think about that, sorry, I deleted my answer

Comment: Have you looked into the [Visual Viewport API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Visual_Viewport_API) yet?

Comment: For future readers, `visualViewport.offsetLeft` and `visualViewport.offsetTop` are the required x/y coordinates. Thanks to @EssXTee for the help.